# How to include a digital clock using java script in a php page without "borrowing" it from any other site just like the one given in the code?

Tags: javascript, flash

Need a method to get a digital clock without taking it from sites like 24timezones.com

```
<script src="http://24timezones.com/timescript/maindata.js.php?city=1595976"language="javascript"></script>**strong text**
<table width="8">
      <tr>
       <td width="83"><div id="flash_container_tt52b882f044241"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var flashMap = new SWFObject("http://24timezones.com/timescript/clock_digit_24.swf", "main", "1360", "70", "7.0.22", "#FFFFFF", true)
        flashMap.addParam("movie",      "http://24timezones.com/timescript/clock_digit_24.swf");
        flashMap.addParam("quality",    "high");
        flashMap.addParam("wmode",      "transparent");
        flashMap.addParam("flashvars",  "color=00CC00&logo=1&city=1595976");
        flashMap.write("flash_container_tt52b882f044241");
          </script></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: will i be able to include a .swf file ???

Comment: Look...we're here to help with actual coding problems. You're not doing coding. You're just trying to steal someone else's code. If you want to write your own clock, then by all means, do so... and we'll try to help fix that code. But we're not here to help you steal others' work.

Comment: All that code is doing is initializing a flash object _using_ JavaScript. It would be much easier to just write a pure JavaScript clock on your own. Start with `(new Date()).getTime()`.

Comment: Please note that question tags are expected to describe your question, nor your web site. If you want to "borrow" a Flash app and load it with JavaScript, it's pretty irrelevant that your site runs PHP. I've re-tagged to the best of my ability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

W3Schools [has an excellent example](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_timing_clock) in pure JavaScript:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function startTime()
{
var today=new Date();
var h=today.getHours();
var m=today.getMinutes();
var s=today.getSeconds();
// add a zero in front of numbers<10
h=checkTime(h);
m=checkTime(m);
s=checkTime(s);
document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML=h+":"+m+":"+s;
t=setTimeout(function(){startTime()},500);
}

function checkTime(i)
{
if (i<10)
  {
  i="0" + i;
  }
return i;
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="startTime()">
<div id="txt"></div>
</body>
</html>
```