# Library Function in PHP to Put a live timer in it

Tags: php

is it possible to place a live timer in PHP page 
is their any library Function for it 
and timer get refresed without whole page getting refresed

Comment: You probably want this functionality in JavaScript, not PHP. https://www.google.com/webhp#q=javascript+digital+clock

Comment: Nope, you need JavaScript for this. You can use PHP to get the time from the server, but you still need an AJAX call to the PHP file if you don't want the page to refresh. So without page refresh? Use JavaScript. And you can take a look at moment.js, works great

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to include a digital clock using java script in a php page without "borrowing" it from any other site just like the one given in the code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21141087/how-to-include-a-digital-clock-using-java-script-in-a-php-page-without-borrowin)

Comment: You should specify what you want to do...

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax if you want particular div to get refresh. But from my experience you should use javascript instead of PHP.

You can use jquery timer library and implement the same as under

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.timer.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 

        var seconds = <?php echo 600; ?>;


        var timer = $.timer(
        function() {
            seconds--;


            var hr=Math.floor(seconds/(60*60));
            var min=Math.floor((seconds / 60) % 60);
            var sec=seconds % 60; 

            <?php

            $_session['hr']=hr;
            $_session['min']=min;
            $_session['sec']=sec;

            ?>
            $('.count').html(hr+ " : " + min + ":" + sec);
        },
        1000,   
        true
    );  




    </script> 

    <div class="count">

    </div>
```

The js file you can find it [here](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-timer/)